# String value not showing two variable values

Tags: java

I would like to set a String value to `fileName + ".yaml" + comment != null ? comment : "" + date.toString()`where fileName and comment are of type String but the expression does not show the filenema.yaml and the date but only the comment if that one is not null. What is the problem in my expression?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I strongly *suspect* the problem is precedence. I expect it's being treated as:

```java
String value = (fileName + ".yaml" + comment) != null ? comment : "" + date.toString();
```

That first expression is never going to be null, so it will always take the second operand of the conditional operator instead of the third. Even then, I think that code is unclear in terms of precedence... I would definitely make it more explicit.

I suspect you actually want it to parse as:

```java
String value = fileName + ".yaml" + (comment != null ? comment : "") + date.toString();
```

... so make that explicit. Note that you don't need the `toString()` call - that's implicit because you're using string concatenation. So you can just have:

```java
String value = fileName + ".yaml" + (comment != null ? comment : "") + date;
```

(I suspect there are simpler ways of expressing this with string formatting, but it should at least do what you want.)

Another alternative would be to move the conditional operator to a separate statement:

```java
String commentOrEmpty = comment == null ? "" : comment;
String value = fileName + ".yaml" + commentOrEmpty + date;
```